# Как открыть папку с файлами Android

Tags: java, android, логирование, text

Мое приложение пишет логи в текстовые файлы, каждый день, месяц, год, создается новая папка с файлами.
Каким образом можно открыть папку с логами, чтобы обзор происходил в стандартном просмотрщике?

Просто как показала практика, у многих юзеров нет ни единого файлового менеджера, а обязать их что-то устанавливать я не в праве.
Нужен рабочий способ, чтобы у всех была возможность, даже не имея файлового менеджера, открыть папку с файлами и просмотреть текстовые логи.

Answer (score 1):

"Стандартного просмотрщика" в Android не существует. А значит у пользователя может не быть никакого. То есть единственный выход, это научить ваше приложение выбирать файл и отображать его содержимое.

Можете написать сами небольшой файловый менеджер для выбора файла или воспользоваться какой нибудь [билиотекой](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35).

После выбора файла, можно его считать и отображать хоть в `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Запускаем интент с файл-менеджером (есть стандартный в андроиде)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923760/how-to-use-intent-for-choosing-file-browser-to-select-file

В качестве аргумента при запуске указываем путь до ваших логов.

```
....  
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_RESULT_CODE);
....
```

Comment: Хоть и по ссылке есть решение, лучше его опубликовать сюда.